# How can I set attribute Name dynamically in handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have data in `json` format just like in the following way.

```
var json={time:"10",temp:"20",attributeValue:valueWillchangeDynamically}
```

handleBars Template:

```
 <input type="text" value="{{unitValue2}}">
```

what I want,

If `attributeValue` equals to `time`, my handlebars template should be like

```
 <input type="text" value="{{time}}">
```

If `attributeValue` equals to `temp`, my handlebars template should be like

```
 <input type="text" value="{{temp}}">
```

that means, I want to pass attribute name also dynamically.

please can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way forward for you might be to write a Handlebars helper function which will check for the condition equality and manipulate your template accordingly.

Check out the helpers section [here](http://handlebarsjs.com/)